# Where clause does not seem to work

Tags: sas

I have the following code in SAS with which I I try to get a dataset where the values of abo_id and abo_bklantid do not match.

```
data set_2
 set final_set;
 where abo_id != abo_bklant_id;
run;
```

This however trows the following error:

```
ERROR: Syntax error while parsing WHERE clause.
ERROR: No input data sets available for WHERE statement.
ERROR 56-185: SET is not allowed in the DATA statement when option   DATASTMTCHK=COREKEYWORDS.  Check for a missing semicolon in the 
          DATA statement, or use DATASTMTCHK=NONE.

ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, 
          a missing value, INPUT, PUT.  

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

Any thoughts where I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon on your first line :-)

```
data set_2;  /* <<< here! */
 set final_set;
 where abo_id ne abo_bklant_id; /* <<< cannot use != in SAS */
run;
```

Also (credit Robert S.) the `!=` operator is not valid in SAS.

Comment: In SAS there is no `!=` operator. Use `^=` or `ne` or `<>` operator instead.

Comment: Don't use <> to mean not equal.  In most of SAS that is the MAX operator, not the NE operator. `-1 <> 0` is 0 since 0 is larger than -1.  But `-1 ^= 0` is 1 since -1 is not equal to 0.

Comment: I should make a t-shirt.  "<> ^= NE".  Only about ten people in the world will understand it.